# Exit bash script after all applications finish

Tags: bash, konsole

I have the following bash script that runs few instances of my program simultaneously:

```
#!/bin/bash

./my_scrape &
./my_scrape &
./my_scrape &
exit 0
```

After some time I see that all instances successfully finished, but the script does not exit - I need to press Enter for that in Konsole. Removing `exit 0` doesn't help. How can I make the script finish correctly?

Comment: I think that the script has exited, but the Konsole session has not, does your script open the Konsole session, or do you do that, then launch the script?

Comment: @Arronical I do open Konsole and type `./myscript.sh`

Comment: How do you know that the script hasn't finished, is it because you don't get a command prompt?

Comment: @Arronical Yes, I need to press Enter for that.  The program doesn't pause anywhere and runs ok if launched separately.

Comment: What does myscript.sh do?

Comment: @Anwar It runs multiple instances of my program `my_scrape` at once.  The scrapers work fine and finish their tasks.  The problem is that I don't see when the process is finished, because the script does not return to command prompt.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why it wouldn't, the my-scrape program is being run in the background, and there are no `wait`s set to keep the script going until the programs complete. The script should just return to the command prompt immediately.

Comment: @Arronical  Thats the github with the scraper, also I have uploaded the video there, please check:  https://github.com/hcl14/model_detection/tree/master/scrape